# C Multiples of a number from 1 to 100 going over 100

Tags: c

I'm creating a program that calculates the multiples of seven from 1 to 100. However my code prints one multiple above 100, 105. I'm not sure how to fix this. I've tried doing num <= 100, num < 100, num < 99, num = 0, but nothing works. Thank you!

Code:

```
int main()
{
 //variables
 int i = 1, num;

 printf("Multiples of Seven from 1 to 100: \n");
 while(num < 100) {
    num = i * 7;
    printf(" %d ", num);
    i++;
 } //while end
} //main end
```

Comment: Hint: What value does `num` start with? What value does an uninitialized variable have?

Comment: Tip: This would be better written as a `for` loop. You also don't need `num` at all.

Comment: Tip: you should  check  ```while( i*7 < 100)``` , this would solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make while loop condtion as,

```
while(i * 7 <= 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

or change the lines from this:

```
num = i * 7;
printf(" %d ", num);
```

to this:

```
printf(" %d ", num);
num = i * 7;
```

if you choose to go this way you should initialize num..

this is the output

```
Multiples of Seven from 1 to 100: 
 0  7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84  91  98
```

Comment: Works in getting rid of the extra multiple, but it prints an 8 in front

Comment: @Kaiju you have to initialize your ```num``` value to ```7``` before starting the ```While loop```.